# Best practice for Anaconda install in a directory that requires root access

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am running Arch Linux and I have just installed anaconda2 via the AUR. Anaconda is installed in /opt/anaconda2. I can activate anaconda via this command

```
source /opt/anaconda2/bin/activate root
```

I noticed that I can only install packages as my user if I append the pip install with --user and conda doesn't work that option. Then the packages are installed in

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

but the anaconda environment can't see the packages unless I add it to the path with export. My question is really how do I add my local packages to path of anaconda? So that they are available when I activate the environment? Or would be better to install anaconda locally in my home directory instead as a user? I know that you clone the anaconda install to local directory. What would be the best approach here?

Comment: It is better to install Anaconda/Miniconda locally. It has been designed to work without ever requiring elevated privileges.

Comment: I will do that then. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user needs write permission on the Anaconda or Miniconda directory structure. However, this can be achieved by group permissions as well as user permissions. Check if Arch Linux installed `/opt/anaconda2/` with a special group, for example "anaconda". If so, you can add your user to that group to get access.

Three more things to consider:

- Your Anaconda version seems to be backlevel. In recent versions, the former "root" environment has been renamed to "base".
- If you're planning to create your own Anaconda environments, it is better to use Miniconda instead of Anaconda.
- Python 2 reaches end of life in a few months. Use Ana/Miniconda3 instead of 2.

If those packages aren't available in Arch Linux, I agree with merv's suggestion in a comment: Get the installers directly from Anaconda, rather than using the Arch Linux package manager.

Comment: The anaconda package in arch doesn't create a group, so I have just uninstalled it and installed the version from the website in my local home directory. The reason choose version 2 it that the only course I am following is using that. I myself was a bit surprised that they used version 2 even though the course is only  about 2 years old. Doesn't Anaconda have a clone function so that can build your own environments? Why is Miniconda better there?